# Install RubyGems on GoDaddy shared hosting?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I just moved my domains over to GoDaddy without knowing that they pulled all Ruby support as of late last month and I kind of need Ruby for what I was planning on building. I've seen guides like [this one](http://c.kat.pe/installing-ruby-gems-on-dreamhost) that detail how to install Ruby through [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) on shared hosting. I made it through the guide but still wasn't able to load gems to my home directory.

Does anyone have any experience with this or any guidance? I guess doing it through RubyGems into the home directory isn't the same as installing on the server, so it should bypass the shared server restrictions. I just can't get any "gem" commands to run. I was probably screwing up the edits to the bash_profile, though.

Comment: try using [`rvm`](http://rvm.io) to install ruby

Comment: Didn't work - all sorts of errors popped up because of locked down access on the shared server. Thank you, though!

Comment: use rvm/rbenv. install it into your home folder, and dont use any `sudo` operation. then install a new ruby version, which will include gem app, then install gems into a gemset.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the head of Product for Hosting at GoDaddy and wanted to jump in.

We did EOL support for Ruby on our legacy shared platform (there were literally a handful of people using it) but the plan is that once we get the cPanel-based shared Linux platform up to where we want it we will reintroduce Ruby and even have support for Rails. ;-)

Right now we're not there but it is coming. I'm betting it isn't in the next month or so given the list of things we're working on for the core product but we will be supporting it in the not too distant future.

Bill

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation, Bill! Excited for support to come back. I'll wait patiently until then. :-)

Comment: So...Does GoDaddy supports Ruby now?